# Distributed computing in Python - network costs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

I have a built a way to distribute a verification-based application over multiple machines using the following excellent blog post as a starting point:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/24/distributed-computing-in-python-with-multiprocessing

…which itself is based on the Python multiprocessing docs (see the section on managers, remote managers and proxy objects):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

However, for my application at least, I have noticed that the networking costs are not constant, but rather grow (at first glance linearly) with the overall verification time, to the point where the cost is no longer acceptable (from a handful of seconds to hundreds). **Is there a way to minimise these costs, and what is most likely to be driving them?**

In my setup, the server machine opens a server at a given port. The clients then connect and read jobs from a single jobs queue and put finished/solved jobs to a single reporting queue - these queues are registered multiprocessing.Queue() queues. When a result to the verification problem is returned, or the queue is empty, the server sends a multiprocessing.Event() signal to the clients, allowing them to terminate. With clients terminated, the server/controller machine then shuts down the server.

In terms of costs, I think can of the following:

- the cost of opening the server (payed once)
- the cost of keeping the server ‘open’ (is this a real cost?)
- the cost of accepting connections from clients (payed once per client)
- the cost of reading/writing from/to the serialized queues (variable)

In terms of the last cost, writing to the jobs queue by the controller machine is performed only once (though the number of items can vary). The amount a client reads from the jobs queue and writes to the reporting queue is variable, but tends to occur only a handful of times before the overall verification problem is complete, as opposed to hundred of times.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Jdorri. One of the Community principles is to use a MCVE-based problem presentation - a **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of the code, that you struggle to make working as expected. So the best next step would be to update your first post, so as to meet the MCVE-standard, as you ask other contributing members to help you with a problem - so make it complete (incl. data, settings & el) and post also your records of evidence where & to what extent your efforts failed to serve your needs. That's fair, isn't it? Enjoy being the active contributing member